# Plot from matplotlib and pandas is not working with data json file because ValueError

Tags: python, json, pandas, matplotlib

I tried generate a simple plot, but error here.
My code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


real_estates = pd.read_json('/Users/pablo/Desktop/project/REscraper/real_estates.json')

# print(real_estates)

plt.plot(real_estates.size, real_estates.price)

plt.show()
```

real_estates.json

```
[
{"price": 298000.0, "size": 47.45, "rooms": 3, "price_per_square_meter": 6280.0},
{"price": 599000.0, "size": 73.0, "rooms": 2, "price_per_square_meter": 8205.0},
[...]
]
```

Error:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (2500,)
```

Someone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[size](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.size.html) happens to be an attribute of a DataFrame. Use a [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) or `.loc` to *select* the column

```
plt.plot(real_estates['size'], real_estates['price'])
# or
plt.plot(real_estates.loc[:,'size'], real_estates.loc[:,'price'])
```

---

[Indexing and selecting data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing)